# In Sharepoint 2010 Service accounts permissions on SQL server and databases

Tags: 2010, permissions, security

In sharepoint 2010 and sql server 2012 r2  which permissions need on sharepoint databases and sql server roles for below service accounts.

service accounts:

- Spfarm account
- spadmin account
- search service application account
- Web application Pool account
- Service application pool account

Databases:

- Configuration database
- Search Service application databases
- Content databases
- Service applications database(managed metadata)

SQL Server Roles above service accounts:

1. is Spfarm account should be db_owner for all above databases?
2. Search service should be db_owner  for all search databases?
3. Search service and spfarm account need any permissions on master and tempdb also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spfarm account and spadmin account following accounts required the SecurityAdmin and DB_Creator  on SQL Server.When you provision any service using the farm account then SharePoint will set the permission. All the required permissions, Role automatically fixed during the provisioning process. I never saw any issue to manually set the permission within farm.

I do see the issue when you have separate Services farm.

1. is Spfarm account should be db_owner for all above databases?
   **Yes**
2. Is Search service should be db_owner for all search databases? 
   **Yes**
3. Search service and spfarm account need any permissions on master and
   tempdb also? **No**

Comment: Hi for some reason  some default permissions for sharepoint dbs including search and content dbs removed, and  crawling was stuck in search content sources and spadmin user can not create any databases in this farm, really Search service and spfarm account not require any permissions on master and tempdbs??

Comment: Nope they dont need any permission, rather you have to make sure that Farmadmin  account has Dbcreator and Security admin rights on the SQL server

Comment: Hi thanks, again is application pool  account for web application needed db_owner  database permissions in content database?

Comment: I know we have set app pool account as dbo on content db. I am not sure what is default value as no VM ready for me :).